# PHP Login Script always prints "wrong username or password"

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I'm currently trying to create a login script for my website, here is the code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting (E_ALL);

ob_start();

$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="1234";
$dbname="thewebsite";
$tbl_name="Accounts"; 

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname)or die("cannot connect"); 

$myusername=$_POST['user']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['pass']; 

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $myusername);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE userName='$myusername' and passwd='$mypassword'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count==1) {
session_register("user");
session_register("pass"); 
header("location:loginsuccess.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

For some reason it will always show "Wrong Username or Password, even if it is correct. Here's the database:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS thewebsite;
CREATE DATABASE thewebsite;
USE thewebsite;

CREATE TABLE Accounts (
    emailAddress VARCHAR(255),
    userName VARCHAR(20),
    passwd VARCHAR(128)
);

INSERT INTO Accounts VALUES ("xxx@mail.com", "xxx", MD5("xxx"));
```

I really can't work out what the problem is, I'm using MySQL 5.6.17.0, PHP 5.5.10 and Apache 2.4.9

Comment: you are comparing the users raw password against the md5 hash in the db. more importantly md5 is broken, don't use it, and saltt the pw, too

Comment: MD5 (groan) Use this => http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471

Comment: the cool kids use md6

Comment: Wow, can't believe that, thanks guys.

Comment: Interesting @Dagon I'll have to look into it mah-self ;-) In a nutshell, how is it compared to CRYPT_BLOWFISH?

Comment: its far less sexually suggestive.

Comment: Now that's boring. Where's the fun in that? @Dagon

Comment: Also, you should not store the password in the session, for two reasons: 1. it serves no purpose and 2. unless you've done something non-standard with session storage, session data will be saved in the local file system and although access to the sessions folder will be restricted, if someone got root/admin access to the server then all the passwords for the users with unexpired sessions will be vulnerable. (This assumes you're not using the Suhosin option, which encrypts the session data, but still, even if you are, there's no need to store the password in the session).

Comment: Don't know if you could help me again but MySQL workbench freezes A LOT, especially when I click "Execute" on a databse. Know why?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE userName='$myusername' and passwd='$mypassword'";
```

into:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE userName='$myusername' and passwd=MD5('$mypassword')";
```

Although instead mysql's MD5() I'd use PHP's password hashing API (password_hash, password_verify, etc.).